# PHP - List and open files in a directory

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to list the content of a specific directory as links and want the browser to open or download the files if I click on them, as it normaly would do like a default html file-link, but the links are not working, if I click.
If I right-click and copy the link and paste to a new tab, it opens the file.

My code:

```
<?php 
    $dir = 'c:/dir/work';
    $files = scandir($dir);
    $filecount = count($files);
    for ($i=0; $i <= $filecount ; $i++) { 
      if ($files[$i] != '.' && $files[$i] != '..') {
        echo '<p><a href="' . $dir . '/' . $files[$i] . '">' . $dir . '/' . $files[$i] . '</a></p>';

      }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look suggested code for auto download file when click on generated link.

```
<?php 
 $dir = 'c:/dir/work';
 $files = scandir($dir);
 $filecount = count($files);
 for ($i=0; $i <= $filecount ; $i++) { 
   if ($files[$i] != '.' && $files[$i] != '..') {
     echo '<p><a href=?file=' . $dir . $files[$i] . '>' . $dir . '/' . $files[$i] . '</a></p>';

   }
 }
if(isset($_GET['file'])){
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($_GET['file']) . "\""); 
    readfile($_GET['file']); 
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You ought to have a central processing script for all the files you want to download. So your href will point to the script instead of file itself like this:

```
echo '<p><a href="downloadfile.php?path=' . $dir . '/' . $files[$i] . '">' . $dir . '/' . $files[$i] . '</a></p>';
```

And in this script, you need to send content-disposition header for the files to get download, instead of being displayed inline, like this:

```
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$_GET['path']);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replys. I tried them, but did not work for me. I think I miss the basics for this.
Finaly I figured out something else:

```
// LIST FILES FROM UPLOADS/SUBDIR BY DAY-ID
function list_files_from_subdir ($subdir, $day_id) {

    $upload = wp_upload_dir ();
    $dir = $upload[basedir] . $subdir;
    $url = $upload[baseurl] . $subdir;
    $files = scandir($dir);
    $filecount = count($files);

    for ($i=0; $i <= $filecount ; $i++) {

      $fileday = substr($files[$i], 0, 8);

      if ($day_id == $fileday) {

        echo '<p><a href="' . $url . $files[$i] . '" target="_blank">' . $files[$i] . '</a></p>';

      }

    }

}
```